# .htaccess rewriting for custom coded MVC platform

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to write my own MVC platform in PHP for a school project and facing a problem with my .htaccess file. After following several tutorials and reading answers here on Stackoverflow I am still failing at getting it right. Briefly, I am rewriting requests to the root domain to index.php and then calling my router to get the controller and so on, everything is working fine except for one thing, sometimes and for no apparent reason I type a URL like mydomain.com/page and it changes to mydomain.com/index.php?/page 
here is the code I have, a colleague has the same code and it is working! 
any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

if i type the www. before the domain name it always goes to /index.php?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the first `RewriteRule` gets applied which rewrites the `${REQUEST_URI}` variable and then the second `RewriteRule` applies which performs a redirect on the already *rewritten* `${REQUEST_URI}`. As RewriteCond only ever apply to [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/354802/how-do-i-reset-apaches-rewritecond-directive) RewriteRule you can check the www. and http first:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

This will redirect you first before actually rewriting the URL